# Inner HTML - correct form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert html depending on whether a user has selected a facebook page or not. As of now my main function (searchOrDropdown()) is not working. I am trying to troubleshoot and I want to make sure that I am using the inner.HTML js method in the correct manner.

Thank you!

```
 var getDropDown = function () {
        return '
    <div class="btn-group page-actions" dropdown is-open="status.isopen" id ="dropdown_html">
        <button id="button_current_page_name" type="button" class="btn background-color-transparent color-text dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="user_pages_selected">Loading your Facebook pages...</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        </button>
        <ul id="ul_user_pages_list" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        </ul>
    </div>';
        };

var getSearchBar = function () {
        return '
        <div class="search-wrapper">    
            <form>
                <input style="border-radius:15px" onkeyup ="PagesDropDown.pageValueDidChange(value)" style= "margin-top: 0.5cm" type="text" value="" required class="search-box" placeholder= "Enter your page" autofocus>
            </form> 
        </div>';
    };

 var searchOrDropdown=function(value)
    {
         //TODO find the wrapper element
        var wrapper = document.getElementById("sdparent_wrapper"));
        if (!FacebookPage.currentPage) {
            wrapper.innerHTML = getSearchBar();
        } else{
            wrapper.innerHTML = getDropDown();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you checked your developer console for errors?. If so, can you post the error message?

Comment: There's an extra `)` in the line where you instantiate `var wrapper`

Comment: var wrapper = document.getElementById("sdparent_wrapper")); remove last )

Comment: thank you guys for spotting that syntax error. I don't know how I missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue are your linebreaks. Try adding a backslash at the end of each line:

```
 var getDropDown = function () {
    return '\
<div class="btn-group page-actions" dropdown is-open="status.isopen" id ="dropdown_html">\
    <button id="button_current_page_name" type="button" class="btn background-color-transparent color-text dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">\
        <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="user_pages_selected">Loading your Facebook pages...</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>\
    </button>\
    <ul id="ul_user_pages_list" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">\
    </ul>\
</div>';
    };
```

And there is one too many parenthesis in your code, so also change the following:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("sdparent_wrapper");
```

Comment: Oh right, didn't see that. I'll add that to the answer, thanks.

Comment: it looks like this was the problem, for some reason the backslashes didn't have an effect until I put the whole block of code in one line

Comment: That work's too. Often people use arrays and put each line into an array element and then join the array with linebreaks at the end. http://jsfiddle.net/ttj7d2Lo/1/

Answer (score 0):

> change
>           var wrapper = document.getElementById("sdparent_wrapper")); to var wrapper = document.getElementById("sdparent_wrapper")